# compare file permissions between 2 files in bash

Tags: bash, syntax

I am trying to compare the permissions on 2 files but cant seem to get the correct result. Can anyone help.

```
act= stat -c "%a" a
bac= stat -c "%a" b

echo "$act"  # returns correctly eg 777, not sure if this is a string or no.
echo "$bac"  # returns correctly as above


if [[ "$act"="$ghi" ]];
then 
   echo "Correct"
else
   echo "Difference"
fi
```

---

This is currently what I get
It says the properties are the same
1. First time a=777 and b=777
2. Second time a=222 and b=777

```
#!/bin/bash

active= stat -c "%a" a
backup= stat -c "%a" b


echo "$active"
echo "$backup"

if [[ "$active" = "$backup" ]];
then 
        echo "Properties are The Same"
else
        echo "Properties are Different"
fi
```

This is the output i get

```
sandbox-computer work # ./compareFiles_02.sh
777
777
```

Properties are The Same

```
sandbox-computer work # chmod 222 a
sandbox-computer work # ./compareFiles_02.sh
222
777
```

Properties are The Same

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 5):

```
act=$(stat -c "%a" file1)
bac=$(stat -c "%a" file2)

if [[ "$act" = "$bac" ]] # whitespaces added, $ghi replaced by $bac
then 
   echo "Correct"
else
   echo "Difference"
fi
```

Comment: #!/bin/bash

active= stat -c "%a" a
backup= stat -c "%a" b


echo "$active"
echo "$backup"

if [[ "$active" = "$backup" ]];
then 
        echo "Properties are The Same"
else
        echo "Properties are Different"
fi


This is the output i get
sandbox-computer work # ./compareFiles_02.sh
777
777
Properties are The Same

sandbox-computer work # chmod 222 a
sandbox-computer work # 
sandbox-computer work # 
sandbox-computer work # ./compareFiles_02.sh
222
777
Properties are The Same

Comment: @MMouse You need the command substitution: `active=$(stat -c "%a" a)`,  ... Not `active= stat-c "%a" a`

Answer (score 0):

Write the if as `if [ "$act" = "$bac" ];`(recommended) or `if [ "$act" == "$bac" ]`(not recommended).

References: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: Why mention something that aren't recommended? Without explaining *why*?

Comment: The tldp guide is outdated and in some cases just plain wrong. Greg's Bash guide is strongly recommended instead.

Comment: @andlrc The == comparison operator behaves differently within a double-brackets test than within single brackets. The link in answer.

Comment: @MMouse the spaces between the `=` should be as shown in answer. Also do refer link.